# set tab Selected Text Color do not work

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I want to change the color of tab when it's selected .in matrial design tutorial they said by set `tabSelectedTextColor` we can do that. but it did n't work for me .and i force to that in `onTabSelected` like below code:

```
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            TextView v = (TextView) tab.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.text_tab_counter);
            v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            TextView vv=(TextView) tab.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.text_tab);
            vv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Notify));
            v.setText("");
            tab.getCustomView().invalidate();
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

        }
```

why this didn't work out?

**EDIT**
is this becuse i have custom tab layout?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"


    android:layout_gravity="center"
    >
<TextView

    android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:id="@+id/text_tab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <TextView
        android:text="•"
        android:textColor="@color/Notify"
        android:textSize="@dimen/badget_size"
        android:id="@+id/text_tab_counter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

       />

</LinearLayout>
```

Edit:

`ViewPageAdapter` code:

```
    package ir.whc.news.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import ir.whc.news.R;

/**
 * Created by marzieh on 3/31/2016.
 */
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context context;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager, Context context) {
        super(manager);
        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }


    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
    public View getTabView(int position,boolean havenew) {


        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_tab);
        TextView tv2= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_tab_counter);

        tv.setText(getPageTitle(position));
        tv.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.textColorPrimary));
        //tv2.setText(String.valueOf(count));
        //tv2.setVisibility(havenew ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
        tv2.setText(havenew?context.getString(R.string.newBadgerSign):"");
        tv2.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.Notify));

        return v;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this in Material TabLayout:

```
 app:tabTextColor="@color/normal_color"
 app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/selected_color"



<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/CustomTabText"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/text_color"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/text_color"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

And For custom TabLayout add this in getView() method:

`tabTitleView.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.drawable.selector_textview))`;

Add this in your drawable selector_textview.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/selected_color" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/selected_color" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/selected_color" />
    <item android:color="@color/normal_color" />

</selector>
```

Comment: it didn't work out,i edit my question ,is this because custom tab ?

Comment: its for TabLayout provided in Material Design

Comment: will you share the code what you have used for custom tablayout

Comment: i add my ViewPageAdapter  to question .i should how/hide something like badger in tab when new item is availble in lisview inside tab so i forced to add getview method to my viewpager and call this method in `onCreate` method in my activity like this link :https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout#add-custom-view-to-tablayout